# How to set srcObject for a videotag in React while rendering?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a piece of code as such :

```
  function VideoRender() {
    const pRef = React.useRef()
    return incData.map((el, i) => {
      return (
        <div key={i}>
          <video ref={pRef} autoPlay></video>
        </div>
      )
    })
  }
```

I want to set `mediaStream` to the video tag right in the `map` function but apparently I run into errors. What is the proper way of rendering `<video>` and changing the `mediaStream` through `srcObject` in React?

Answer (score 1):

`ref` has a callback so you can do something like this.

```
return (
  <video
    autoPlay
    key={index}
    muted
    ref={(ref) => {
      if (ref) ref.srcObject = remoteStream;
    }}
  />
);
```